# Why I get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default') while connecting with WalletConnectProvider"? in Flutter

Tags: flutter, metamask, wallet-connect, trustwallet, flutter-web3

I am getting the folling error when I want to connect to trustWallet or Metamask through walletconnect with [flutter_web3](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web3) package.

**Error:**

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
    at WalletConnectProvider.fromRpc (wallet_connect.dart:86:7)
    at web3_controller_notifier.Web3ControllerNotifier.new.connectWithWalletConnect (web3_controller_notifier.dart:73:52)
    at connectWithWalletConnect.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
    at web3_controller_notifier.Web3ControllerNotifier.new.connectWithWalletConnect (web3_controller_notifier.dart:72:32)
    at home_page.dart:86:51
    at ink_well._InkResponseState.new.handleTap (ink_well.dart:1084:21)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.invokeCallback (recognizer.dart:282:24)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleTapUp (tap.dart:660:11)
    at [_checkUp] (tap.dart:311:5)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handlePrimaryPointer (tap.dart:244:7)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleEvent (recognizer.dart:647:9)
    at [_dispatch] (pointer_router.dart:98:12)
    at pointer_router.dart:143:9
    at LinkedMap.new.forEach (linked_hash_map.dart:21:13)
    at [_dispatchEventToRoutes] (pointer_router.dart:141:17)
    at pointer_router.PointerRouter.new.route (pointer_router.dart:127:7)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handleEvent (binding.dart:456:19)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (binding.dart:436:14)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (binding.dart:333:11)
    at [_handlePointerEventImmediately] (binding.dart:391:7)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handlePointerEvent (binding.dart:354:5)
    at [_flushPointerEventQueue] (binding.dart:311:7)
    at [_handlePointerDataPacket] (binding.dart:292:7)
    at Object.invoke1 (platform_dispatcher.dart:1221:13)
    at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.new.invokeOnPointerDataPacket (platform_dispatcher.dart:243:5)
    at [_onPointerData] (pointer_binding.dart:167:39)
    at pointer_binding.dart:778:20
    at pointer_binding.dart:707:14
    at loggedHandler (pointer_binding.dart:317:16)
    at pointer_binding.dart:199:80
    at Object._checkAndCall (operations.dart:367:37)
    at Object.dcall (operations.dart:372:39)
    at ret (js_patch.dart:415:11)
```

Called method:

```
 void connectWithWalletConnect() async {
        _walletConnectProvider = WalletConnectProvider.fromRpc(
          {56: 'https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443'},
          chainId: 56,
          network: 'Binance Smart Chain',
          bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org',
        );
    
        await _walletConnectProvider.connect();
        
        print('wallet connect  ${_walletConnectProvider.walletMeta}');
        
        if (_walletConnectProvider.connected) {
          print(_walletConnectProvider.accounts.first);
        }
      }
```